# i want to upload image into public folder and database in laravel but i facing some problem

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload image into public folder and database in *laravel* but I am facing some problem, `Image is uploading into public folder  but image is not saving into database.` Can anyone help me telling where it is going wrong? Here is my code.

**controller**

```
public function clientaction(Request $request)
   {


        $validation = validator::make($request->all(),[
          'select_file' =>'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
        ]);
        if($validation->passes())
        {
         $image = $request->file('select_file');
         $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
         return response()->json([
          'message'   => 'Image Upload Successfully',
          'class_name'  => 'alert-success'
         ]);


        }
        else
         {
          return response()->json([
          'message'   => $validation->errors()->all(),
         'class_name'  => 'alert-danger'
      ]);
     }

     DB::table('logo-clients')->insert([

      'select_file'=> $new_name
  ]);
   }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('DashBoard','AdminController@DashBoard');


Route::get('Clients','AdminController@clients');
Route::post('/ajax_upload/action','AdminController@clientaction')->name('ajaxupload.action');
```

Comment: Zubair, can you please the error or logs (project/storage/logs/laravel**.log) for this function? Thanks.

Comment: currently i don't have error (project/storage/logs/laravel**.log)  in this folder just image is not uploading in database thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you already `return` on when the validation is passed. please look at your code you returned twice on validation passed and on failed. i suggest you to move your code on saving it to the database before you return the `response()->json()` when the validation is passed

Comment: move `DB::table('logo-clients')->insert()` this code block above the `return response()->json()` inside the `$validation->passed()` if statement

Answer (score 2):

because you're already returning value it means the action after that is useless

so you just need to move this

```
DB::table('logo-clients')->insert([

  'select_file'=> $new_name
]);
```

below this part

```
$image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
//move it into here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns after moving file into folder. so database insert code is not executed. your function should be like

```
public function clientaction(Request $request) {

    $validation = validator::make($request->all(),[
      'select_file' =>'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
    ]);
    if($validation->passes())
    {
     $image = $request->file('select_file');
     $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
    }
    else
     {
      return response()->json([
         'message'   => $validation->errors()->all(),
         'class_name'  => 'alert-danger'
      ]);
    }

 DB::table('logo-clients')->insert([

  'select_file'=> $new_name ]); 

return response()->json([
      'message'   => 'Image Upload Successfully',
      'class_name'  => 'alert-success'
     ]);
 }
```